# installing my first WSGI

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am installing a flask app  with apache modewsgi.

I have solved multiple troubles already:
- environment variables
- virtualenv
- file permissions

But now I am really stuck with application name. I have no idea what to write in the "from" directive of WSGI file.

here is my ~user/appname.com/appname.com.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/home/user/appname.com/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/user/appname.com')
from appname.com import app as application
```

which causes the following log.

```
[Mon Apr 08 15:50:26 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170] mod_wsgi (pid=6392): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/appname.com/appname.com.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 08 15:50:26 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Mon Apr 08 15:50:26 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170]   File "/home/user/appname.com/appname.com.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
[Mon Apr 08 15:50:26 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170]     from appname.com import app as application
[Mon Apr 08 15:50:26 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170] ImportError: No module named appname.com
```

However if I remove the the from `appname.com` I can run the .wsgi from python commandline without error but within apache, it throws the error below...

```
[Mon Apr 08 15:27:31 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170] mod_wsgi (pid=6274): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/user/appname.com/appname.com.wsgi'.
[Mon Apr 08 15:27:31 2013] [error] [client 64.120.6.170] TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

*UPDATE:*

Here is a structure of ~user/appname.com/

```
app/
    controller.py
    __init__.py
    models.py
    ...
    static/
        ...
    templates/
config.py
Procfile
README
requirements.txt
run.py
appname.com.wsgi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of how you have structured your directories, you would need to add:

- /home/user

to sys.path.

To explain what the second error is, would need to see what is in 'com.py'.

I would suggest though that it is a very bad idea to name your directory 'appname.com'. The presence of the '.' in the directory name will confuse Python.

Answer (score -2):

turns out that i needed to write

```
from app import app as application
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: I added details in description. The confusion was caused by the fact that needs to repeat app keyword twice when there s only 1 thing called app on hard disk. very confusing.